# mimetools модуль в Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Если **mimetools** убрали из Python3, то чем заменить?

```
mimetools.choose_boundary()
```

А если не убрали то как импортировать если у меня его [здесь](https://snag.gy/3Wh6lG.jpg) нет?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел тут http://python3porting.com/stdlib.html

mimetools   Supplanted by email

Думаю choose_boundary можно реализовать теперь так:

```
import email
e = email.message_from_file(fd)
e.set_boundary('--FORM-BOUNDARY')

for part in e.walk():
    print(part)
```